# Spread operator in React .setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Given the following snippet extracted from a React class component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { active: true }
  }

  deactivate = () => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, active: false })
  }
```

What is the aim of the spread operator into the stopCounter() method? The application also works removing it:

```
  deactivate = () => {
    this.setState({ active: false })
  }
```

Comment: I assume someone mistakenly thought you need to pass the entire state to mutate one attribute

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Both works in that case, but you don't need to use that. Just setting the state will be okay:

```
this.setState({active: false})
```

But let me explain what if you have nested level of states like:

```
state = {
  foo: {
   a: 1,
   b: 2,
   c: 3
  }
}
```

And when you need to update the foo's c state only, then you'll need to merge the state like:

```
this.setState({ foo: {
  ...this.state.foo,
  c: 'updated value'
}})
```

So, the spread syntax merges object with later object. It's similar to [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: Thank you. So in this case is not really needed, but in case of deeper objects, is it recommended to always set the state as mentioned?

Comment: Yes. You got it.

Comment: Thanks. Last thing. Is this to remain the original state immutable?

Comment: States are immutable that's why we do use `setState`

Comment: Can you check this please, 
 @BhojendraRauniyar  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392582/how-to-prevent-duplicate-images-when-uploaded-to-firebase

Comment: [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) say not to read a value from state in the `setState` call. Use `setState(prevState => ({...prevState.foo, c: "updated value"}))` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The second snippet works because React is implicitly doing the spreading for you.  Per [React's documentation for `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> You may [...] pass an object as the first argument to `setState()`: `setState(stateChange[, callback])`. This performs a shallow merge of stateChange into the new state.

Answer (score 2):

The goal is just set `active` to `false` and keep the rest with no modifications.
You can edit a part of your state just passing the required names, and skipping the rest.