# Each then() should return a value or throw

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send push notifications using cloud functions for a group chat system, but i keep getting this error in my terminal: **Each then() should return a value or throw**

Why is this happening?

Here's my code:

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions');

let admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/chatrooms/{chatroomId}/chatroom_messages/{chatmessageId}')
.onWrite((snap, context) => {

    console.log("System: starting");
    console.log("snapshot: ", snap);
    console.log("snapshot.after: ", snap.after);
    console.log("snapshot.after.val(): ", snap.after.val());

    //get the message that was written
    let message = snap.after.val().message;
    let messageUserId = snap.after.val().user_id;
    console.log("message: ", message);
    console.log("user_id: ", messageUserId);

    //get the chatroom id
    let chatroomId = context.params.chatroomId;
    console.log("chatroom_id: ", chatroomId);

    return snap.after.ref.parent.parent.once('value').then(snap => {
        let data = snap.child('users').val();
        console.log("data: ", data);

        //get the number of users in the chatroom
        let length = 0;
        for(value in data){
            length++;
        }
        console.log("data length: ", length);

        //loop through each user currently in the chatroom
        let tokens = [];
        let i = 0;
        for(var user_id in data){
            console.log("user_id: ", user_id);

            //get the token and add it to the array 
            let reference = admin.database().ref("/users/" + user_id);
            return reference.once('value').then(snap => {
                //get the token
                let token = snap.child('messaging_token').val();
                console.log('token: ', token);
                tokens.push(token);
                i++;

                //also check to see if the user_id we're viewing is the user who posted the message
                //if it is, then save that name so we can pre-pend it to the message
                let messageUserName = "";
                if(snap.child('user_id').val() === messageUserId){
                    messageUserName = snap.child('name').val();
                    console.log("message user name: " , messageUserName);
                    message = messageUserName + ": " + message;
                }

                //Once the last user in the list has been added we can continue
                if(i === length){
                    console.log("Construction the notification message.");
                    let payload = {

                        data: {
                            data_type: "data_type_chat_message",
                            title: "Tabian Consulting",
                            message: message,
                            chatroom_id: chatroomId
                        }
                    };


                    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            // See the MessagingDevicesResponse reference documentation for
                            // the contents of response.
                            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                            return response;
                          })
                          .catch(function(error) {
                            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                          });
                }
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should flatten your promise chain. `if(i === length){` is something you would do with oldfashioned callback-hell, but with promises you should chain them and do that final logic in yet another `then` callback. As to the error: when `if(i === length){` is not true, you have no `return` happening.

Comment: If you do a web search for that message, you will find a lot of discussion about it.  It's an eslint warning, and it indicates you might have done something wrong in your code.  You should pay attention to the line number it gives you, so that you can figure out where exactly it's raising the issue.

Comment: Btw, you are `return`ing from the first iteration of your loop, so there's no looping happening.

Answer (score 0):

The message is caused by eslint detecting that you have a `then()` handler that can finish without returning a value or throwing an error.

It is caused by your for loop on the following line because you do not return a value or throw if `data` is empty:

```js
for (var user_id in data) {
```

As others have commented, your for-loop won't execute correctly because you are returning a promise and finishing the handler on only the first iteration.

```js
for (var user_id in data) {
    // ...
    return reference.once('value').then(snap => {
    // ...
}
```

#### Arrays in Firebase RTDB

Based on your code, you encountered some of the issues with working with arrays in the RTDB as detailed in [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Instead of using an array to keep track of a chat room's members (below), it would be best to use a key-value pair approach instead. The value stored in the key-value pair can be a simple `true` value; or it can be given meaning (`true` for admins, `false` for others).

```
// Array-based list
"chatrooms/chatroomId1": {
  "chatroom_messages": { ... },
  "users": [
    "userId1",
    "userId2",
    "userId3"
  ]
}

// RTDB stores above data as:
"chatrooms/chatroomId1": {
  "chatroom_messages": { ... },
  "users": {
    "0": "userId1",
    "1": "userId2",
    "2": "userId3"
  }
}

// Recommeneded: key-value pairs
"chatrooms/chatroomId1": {
  "chatroom_messages": { ... },
  "users": {
    "userId1": true,
    "userId2": false,
    "userId3": false
  }
}
```

The main benefit of such an approach is that delete a user from a room is simpler which will help with cleaning spam users/messages. To delete a user, you just call

```js
firebase.database().ref("chatrooms/chatroomId1/users/userId1").delete();
```

rather than

```js
firebase.database().ref("chatrooms/chatroomId1/users").orderByValue().equalTo("userId1").once('value')
  .then((snap) => snap.delete());
```

Furthermore, sending a notification/message that a user was added or removed could be easily implemented using Cloud Functions defined using:

```js
functions.database.ref('/chatrooms/{chatroomId}/users/{userId}').onCreate(...)
functions.database.ref('/chatrooms/{chatroomId}/users/{userId}').onDelete(...)
```

#### Chaining promises

When working with asynchronous tasks, avoid using for loops entirely because they are prone to causing undetectable mistakes and modern Javascript provides better alternatives. One such method is using the `Promise.all(someArray.map(value => {...}))` idiom [covered in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59234502/3068190).

It was also suggested in the question comments to flatten your promise chain, due to the number of changes needed to do the task efficiently, I decided to just make them and note each change in the code itself. The code below relies on the restructure of the chatroom members list discussed above.

```js
let functions = require('firebase-functions');
let admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(); // CHANGED: Cloud Functions provides the needed environment variables to initialize this for you when called without arguments.

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/chatrooms/{chatroomId}/chatroom_messages/{chatMessageId}') // CHANGED: renamed 'chatmessageId' to 'chatMessageId' (consistent camelCaseStyling)
.onWrite((change, context) => { // CHANGED: renamed 'snap' to 'change' (matches actual type & less ambiguous below)

    if (!change.after.exists()) { // CHANGED: Handle when message was deleted
        // message deleted. abort
        console.log(`Message #${context.params.chatMessageId} in Room #${context.params.chatroomId} deleted. Aborting.`);
        return;
    }

    let messageData = change.after.val(); // CHANGED: avoid calling change.after.val() multiple times

    // console.log("New data written: ", messageData); // CHANGED: Removed verbose log commands.

    let message = messageData.message;
    let messageAuthorId = messageData.user_id; // CHANGED: renamed 'messageUserId' to 'messageAuthorId' (less ambiguous)
    let chatroomId = context.params.chatroomId;

    console.log("New message:", { // CHANGED: merged log commands (less StackDriver API overhead when deployed)
        user_id: messageAuthorId,
        chatroom_id: chatroomId,
        message: message
    });

    let chatroomMembersRef = change.after.ref.parent.parent.child('users'); // CHANGED: only got needed data

    return chatroomMembersRef.once('value')
        .then(snap => {
            // DATABASE STRUCTURE CHANGE: "/chatrooms/{chatroomId}/users" - change array (["userId1", "userId2", "userId3"]) to a userId keyed OBJECT (e.g. {"userId1": true, "userId2": true, "userId3": true})
            let chatroomMemberList = Object.keys(snap.val()); // CHANGED: renamed 'data' to 'chatroomMemberList' (less ambiguous)

            // console.log("Chatroom Members: ", {
            //    count: chatroomMemberList.length,
            //    members: chatroomMemberList
            // });

            // Asyncronously, in parallel, retrieve each member's messaging token
            let chatroomMemberTokenPromises = chatroomMemberList.map((memberId) => { // CHANGED: renamed 'user_id' to 'memberId' (less ambiguous, consistent camelCaseStyling)
                let memberDataRef = admin.database().ref("/users/" + memberId); // CHANGED: renamed 'reference' to 'memberDataRef' (less ambiguous)

                // CHANGED: For each member, get only their registration token (rather than all of their user data)
                let getMessagingTokenPromise = memberDataRef.child('messaging_token').once('value').then((memberTokenSnap) => {
                    console.log("Got messaging token for member #", memberId);
                    return memberTokenSnap.val();
                });

                // If this member is the message author, also get their name to prepend to the notification message.
                if (memberId === messageAuthorId) {
                    let prependUserNamePromise = memberDataRef.child('name').once('value')
                        .then((memberNameSnap) => {
                            let messageAuthorName = memberNameSnap.val();
                            console.log("Message author's name: " , messageAuthorName);
                            message = messageAuthorName + ": " + message;
                        });

                    return Promise.all([getMessagingTokenPromise, prependUserNamePromise])
                        .then(results => results[0]); // only return result of getMessagingTokenPromise
                } else {
                    return getMessagingTokenPromise;
                }
            });

            // Wait for all of the messaging tokens
            return Promise.all(chatroomMemberTokenPromises);
        })
        .then((chatroomMemberTokensArray) => {
            console.log("Constructing the notification message...");
            let payload = {
                data: {
                    data_type: "data_type_chat_message",
                    title: "Tabian Consulting",
                    message: message,
                    chatroom_id: chatroomId
                }
            };

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(chatroomMemberTokensArray, payload)
                .then(function(response) {
                    // See the MessagingDevicesResponse reference documentation for
                    // the contents of response.
                    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                    return response;
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                });
        })
        .catch((error) {
            console.log("Unexpected error:", error)
        });
});
```

Comment: Can someone please just give me a code to fix the problem that's coming from the for loop                                                                                                                                  
for (var user_id in data) {
    // ...
    return reference.once('value').then(snap => {
    // ...
}

Comment: @AyomideAjayi As I covered in this answer, the problem isn't just a mere one-line syntax error in your code - but a collection of issues. The last code block is working code if you change the way you store chat room members. If you don't want to change that, just change `Object.keys(snap.val())` to `snap.val()` and the code will continue to work.