# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined - React Hooks with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm trying to connect my app with an API. It works with classes but I tried to use hooks.

This is the error

> > Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

And this is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";

const Home = () => {
  const [currentState, setNewState] = useState({
    url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=600",
    pokemons: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getApi();
    
    async function getApi() {
      const res = await axios.get(currentState.url);
      setNewState({ pokemons: res.data["results"] });
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      {currentState.pokemons ? (
        <div className="pokemonCards">
          {currentState.pokemons.map((poke) => (
            <PokemonCard key={poke.name} name={poke.name} url={poke.url} />
          ))}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <h1> Loading </h1>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: This should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55247471/2138752

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean `prototype`?

Anyways, when you use `useState`, every instance represents a variable, not the whole state.

So, you have to: `setNewState({ url: myUrl, pokemons: myNewPokemons });`

or, even better:

```
setNewState(prevState => {
    return {
        ...prevState,
        pokemons: myNewPokemons
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While using the useState hook of react whenever we set the state the old state will be cleared and the new state which we passed will be the current state while in class-based components the state would not override the old value and would append the new value to the old value. Here after calling the API you are not passing the URL to the setNewState function and just passing the pokemon. You need to do like this

setNewState(prev=> {...prev , pokemons: res.data["results"]}). This will work